# CoreAnimation automatically restarts when iterationStart is set

Tags: dart, polymer, core-elements

I want to skip the first part of an animation and jump right to let's say 3/4 of the duration. For this purpose I build the following script in Dart.

```
Element target = getTarget(layer.element);
CoreAnimation animation = new CoreAnimation();
animation.target = target;
animation.duration = 2000;
animation.iterationStart = 0.75; // 1500ms
animation.keyframes = [
  {'transform': 'translate(0px, 0px)'},
  {'transform': 'translate(20px, 50px)'}
];

// I also tried to add the following attributes
animation.iterations = 1; // doesnt work 
animation.iterationCount = 1; // doesnt work

animation.play();
```

The animation starts at the correct position, but once it has reached its last keyframe {'transform': 'translate(20px, 50px)'} it jumps back to the first keyframe and play the complete animation again. What for gods sake is happening here? Am I missing something?

Note: I already tried to set iteration count to 1.

Comment: Srsly, I got a down vote? Would someone please explain to me why?...

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `animation.iterations` to 1.

Comment: As stated in my initial question, setting the iterations to 1 does not work.

Comment: You edited your question from `iterationCount` to `iterations`. Please note that there are two attributes `iterationCount` and `iterations`.

Comment: Neither one of them is working. Same effect as before. //added my approaches

Comment: Yeah ... vote my post down because you edited your post. wow.

Comment: No I vote your post down, because it doesn't work. Also the answer you gave states 'try to' and not 'do' which is more like 'well, I have no idea but let's try this or that' and not an answer which is from good value. Thus the down vote. Don't take it personal.